# How does a person determine whether they are a "false Christian" or "inconsistent Christian"?

Tags: soteriology, protestantism, christian-living, christian-identity

Many Protestants believe once saved, always saved. Christians who accept Jesus get saved. They also continue sinning and no one is perfect. My question is to those who hold this position.

I have heard many times people say that continued sinning is also evidence that someone is not a Christian. One can find quite a few Bible verses along these lines:

> 1 John 2:4, "The one who says, “I have come to know Him,” and does not keep His commandments, is a liar, and the truth is not in him."
>
> Matthew 7:21 “Not everyone who says to me, ‘Lord, Lord,’ will enter the kingdom of heaven, but only the one who does the will of my Father who is in heaven. Many will say to me on that day, ‘Lord, Lord, did we not prophesy in your name and in your name drive out demons and in your name perform many miracles?’ Then I will tell them plainly, ‘I never knew you. Away from me, you evildoers!’
>
> 2 Peter 2: If they have escaped the corruption of the world by knowing our Lord and Savior Jesus Christ and are again entangled in it and are overcome, they are worse off at the end than they were at the beginning. It would have been better for them not to have known the way of righteousness, than to have known it and then to turn their backs on the sacred command that was passed on to them. Of them the proverbs are true: “A dog returns to its vomit,” and, “A sow that is washed returns to her wallowing in the mud.”

How does one know, therefore, whether they have "really" become saved? Are all Christians saved? What is the statement really being made here? Many people have prayed to God in Jesus' name at one point in their life, and accepted Jesus' free gift of salvation. Then they went on in their lives and sometimes they made mistakes or they sinned. Many people later had doubt, they went back and forth about what they believe. Is someone who never has any serious doubts the one who can be sure they are a Christian?

Because going by sins, there doesn't seem to be any way to tell. One who kills others can be a "true Christian" while one who has lust in his heart for a woman can be an "unsaved sinner", even though both prayed to God to forgive their sins in the name of Jesus at some point in their lives.

I think passages like this make it clear that trying to determine one's Christian status from sinning is dubious:

> James 2:10 For whoever keeps the whole law and yet stumbles at just one point is guilty of breaking all of it.

So my question is -- what is really being claimed and can you give some consistent framework for people to operate in and determine if they are actually saved or not?

Comment: Nice follow up question - this one seems much more on-topic, although you've still got a lot of questions in it, they all seem closely related.

Comment: I would almost like to try and answer it, despite not believing in "once saved, always saved" - a lot of the questions are still relevant to a Wesleyan perspective as well.

Comment: go ahead. I don't know what the point of artificially restricting ALL the questions on the site to denominations is. I think if people identify what denomination they are coming from in their answer, then all the answers to a question can be found in one place, which is better for people searching the internet.

Comment: In my humble opinion people should have an option to select the denomination in addition to text in their answer. If they don't find their denomination they can choose "other" or "any". That would be better than asking the questioners to restrict their questions. Can someone bring it up on meta?

Comment: The point is so that questions can be factually answered rather than just be people's opinions.  Whether an answer is faithful to a particular viewpoint, can be determined fairly easily. What is a 'true' interpretation of matters in dispute can not.

Comment: Right but the viewpoint should be selected by the answerer, not the questioner. Because then you'd have the SAME question in 4 different places, asked by different people of different viewpoints (presumably the same person will feel bad reposting the question four times, slightly altered)

Comment: Just curious if you've taken the time to read [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) yet.

Comment: This question might get closed because it seem almost unanswerable (and I don't blame those who might think this) but I think it should stay open as it is answerable and important to be answered, otherwise the gospel is of no practical value to anyone.

Comment: I am trying to get to the core of your question in order to understand it. So this is a serious question about your question. 'What does it matter?' What, in other words, is the difference between somebody that is saved and somebody that believes they are saved? If I truly believe that I am the Queen of England then I am either the Queen or crazy, and crazy people all go to heaven. People that believe they will go to heaven, will go to heaven and people that believe they will go to hell, will go to hell. That is how I think so as you can see, I cannot even comprehend your question.

Comment: @gideonmarx the bible is quite clear about the fact that there will be people who are deceived about their eternal destination (they will expect to enter into eternal life, but they will not - they have a 'false assurance') - cf. Matt 7:21 quoted in the OP, and also Matt 25 (whole chapter).  The question effectively asks - How can we avoid being deceived in this way?

Comment: re asking the same questions to different viewpoints, the questioner obviously doesn't *have* to do that, and he can quite happily restrict himself to investigating only the viewpoints that are of most relevance/interest. A modicum of research before framing each question will help you to craft each question individually to elicit a deeper response geared to the nuance of differing doctrines.

Comment: @bruisedreed. If you believe you are saved your lamp never goes out. You never go and buy oil and miss the party. Your lamp might be dry and dead but you believe it shines forth. You are delusional. You wait for the groom and you go into the wedding feast with the other virgins. The delusional believe they have a money tree growing and proudly show it off when the lord returns. The delusional do not have a clue what poverty there is in the world. They proudly give their charity. The delusional are not deceived. So, what does it matter?

Comment: @gideonmarx From a Christian perspective - It matters, oh, how it matters!  Contrary to your assertions, the delusional/deceived will not remain so forever, they will discover their error at the judgment if not before. Their salvation *is* really at issue - their false assurance is a flimsy cloak to their false worship that will be exposed and found wanting.  Even from an atheistic perspective it matters as not addressing the issue leads to a multiplication of hypocrites - more people living inconsistently with recognisably good Christian morals such as love your neighbor/enemy.

Comment: @bruisedreed. The deluded remain delusional. I do not imply that you are, but if you, or all Christians, are delusional, how would I know? You could be writing all this stuff about being saved and I cannot know that it is all delusion. All Christianity could be a mass delusion. There is no way of knowing but the entire point about religion is that it does not matter if it is delusion. If you found out that everything you believed was a delusion, would you do evil? Its the works and being faithful to Jesus that are important. Not going to heaven or hell. So this question makes no sense to me.

Comment: Well there are two options to consider: Firstly, if everything is a skillfully crafted delusion that is not discernible from reality, then you are right, there is no point trying to work out what is true as you will just fail and you may as well no worry; But the second option is much more likely - delusions are not ultimate, but have 'cracks' - inconsistencies - that are revealed to impartial outsiders and with sufficient effort can be self-realised and overcome. The OP is focusing on one of these 'cracks' in a 'false assurance' mindset.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15132/discussion-between-bruised-reed-and-gideon-marx).

Answer (score 4):

First, there is a framework in the Bible to help believers identify themselves as being ‘genuine’ or not. However, although this framework is infallible to guide the elect into an 'assurance of salvation' it provides no reliable means to an unbeliever. A wicked soul can and will deceive themselves as part of the curse they are under. Secondly, this framework is ‘personal’ as it involves the ‘internal witness’ of the Holy Spirit and does not extend to an infallible judgment of another person's state.  There is a framework for that (for discerning the sate of others) but it is more general and less determinative primarily for the purpose of identifying false teachers. To answer your question then I will define the scope to be; “an individual who is trying to determine for their own conscience sake, whether they are really saved or no.”  I am answering as someone who firmly believes in once saved always saved. Naturally the question therefore as regarding whether my faith is genuine or not is the most important question I could ever ask myself.

In a nutshell: **Anyone who has genuine faith in Christ by relying on his death, in order to be relieved from a genuine sense of condemnation and fear of eternal punishment for their sins and a corresponding genuine relief of that fear by faith, is most likely a genuine believer.** The question therefore amounts to how can one determine ‘a genuine fear of hell’ and a corresponding ‘genuine relief and peace with God’ by trusting in his death for one’s forgiveness and justification.  To answer one first must be clear that such faith is truly in Christ and not based on works of the law, or practicing any religious rules under any Church claimed authority, effectively replacing faith in Christ with faith in Church, church doctrine, or church practice. In essence if one has never even accepted that a person can be saved by doing nothing more then simple faith, then they are automatically excluded from having any biblical assurance of salvation as they are trusting something in addition to a personal reliance on Christ's work. In addition anyone who has this genuine conviction that Christ’s death is sufficient to provide salvation apart from works of the law, baptism into a particular denomination, or any other external work, has only genuinely come to share in that faith if they are found to persevere to the end with it:

> We have come to share in Christ, if indeed we hold our original conviction firmly to the very end (NIV Heb 3:14).

Therefore one part of the framework is that ‘faith in Christ’ as a means to obtain peace from a fear of eternal damnation can’t be fully destroyed in one who has come to have it. Although this is only a guide it is very helpful because a person who thinks they had become a Christian but then falls into various sins and begins to deny that they had salvation and no longer has any relief of salvation and no longer feels any need for relief because they no longer fear eternal damnation for the guilt of their sin, which faith is to relive, has obviously never been saved in the first place.

We have now narrowed the question therefore to those who have fallen into various external, or internals sins, yet still fear eternal damnation and still find some measure of relief and hope that Christ has and does forgive them for their sin.  The question is while in this condition how can a person know if they have genuine faith, or no? One way to narrow the question further is to apply doctrinal tests. For example, if anyone denies a fundamental doctrine of the gospel, such as that “Christ is God and became man, and who died as an atoning sacrifice for sin". If they are to deny this type of doctrine then their faith is not in Christ as only God could have lived a holy life perfectly under the strict severity of the law and only a man could through blood be a proper sacrifice for human sin. Therefore such a faith could not be genuinely believing in Christ as a means of taking on the punishment of our sin, and no genuine relief could be obtained under the false doctrine.

> Every spirit that acknowledges that Jesus Christ has come in the flesh is from God, 3 but every spirit that does not acknowledge Jesus is not from God. (NIV 1 Jn 4:2–3).

Third, a person with faith has the Spirit of God, which means at a minimum they value God above all other things. It is impossible to genuinely believe in hell, one’s proper eternal damnation for the least sin and eternal salvation offered by simple faith in Christ and not secretly value Christ above any other thing. It is not rational to believe Christ and at the same time not value him above all things. Even the weakest believer must value Christ above all or they have never had any faith whatsoever.

We have now narrowed the question to this: **For those believers who hold to the primary doctrines of the gospel such as original sin, the trinity, justification by faith in Christ apart from works, etc. and hold him in view as something more valuable then anything else and from fear of eternal damnation find some comfort and relief in his death so that they are not driven to insanity with the otherwise extreme fear that they would rationally hold under their conviction, if they were to fall into various sins, internal or external, how can they know if they have ever had genuine faith, or no?**

We now come to a very personal aspect of the question. For outwardly no man would be able to determine who has genuine faith for the confession of the mouth is right, the person seems to have genuine faith, yet they may be not going to church for a long period, may be living in an adulterous relationship, etc.  For example there was a member of the Corinthian church that was having sexual relations with his father’s wife (I guess a kind of Mother in law). One would never know if this person had genuine faith but after being excommunicated from the church it turned out that his faith possibly was genuine and he repented of his sin. Yet, here we find another principle. When it is very unclear if a person is a Christian, or not, it is best to assume not and then the fear of hell will drive one back to the comfort and relief of salvation in Christ.

Still, the answer is not sufficient. For many who are backslidden may be so because there faith in Christ is weak and there fear of condemnation great.  From this weak faith they stumble into many sins and this only heightens their fear of hell so they try not to think about it. In such a case excommunication and warnings of hell only drive them deeper into despair, so they really need to be reminded of the free grace in Christ and find encouragement to go to him for relief of their fear. In this struggle, to differentiate the condemnation of the Devil who accuses the elect, versus the practical duty of one to encourage their own soul although eternally saved to fear hell more and to encourage ones return back to faith for relief, only the Holy Spirit’s internal witness can distinguish.  The fact is that those who have been regenerated by the Holy Ghost as a result of first being justified freely by the grace in Christ, through faith, apart from the works of the law, have an internal witness of the Holy Ghost. Not only so by the Holy Ghost is also the one who preserves correct doctrine in the mind of the believer. (1 John 2:20)

> The Spirit you received does not make you slaves, so that you live in fear again; rather, the Spirit you received brought about your adoption to sonship. And by him we cry, “Abba, Father.” 16 The Spirit himself testifies with our spirit that we are God’s children. (NIV Ro 8:15–16)

**The conclusion:** The elect who have genuinely trusted in Christ receive relief from there dread of eternal damnation and consolation that is never fully destroyed. They therefore persevere and although possibly stumbling into various sins, they never loose that fear of hell and comfort of faith to rescue them from it and therefore return or keep returning to live a life not dominated by the sins they used to commit prior to believing in Christ. During the times when they are down and the conclusion is not clear they are willing to assume the worst and encourage themselves to fear hell in order to arouse their own soul into obedience to faith. However when being accused by the Devil and condemned and so discouraged and fallen into sin through doubt, the Holy Spirit himself will provide assurance so that faith is not snuffed out and a bruised reed not broken, with the final conclusion that the believer will always persevere with faith and be swallowed up in glory forever. *Sometimes it is not clear and is not meant to be clear as God himself provides the assurance to the elect ensuring their perseverance.*

Comment: Read the question again. How will a person know - your reply, they will have little fear of hell. Atheists have no fear of condemnation or of hell or any of that stuff. Does that mean they are all saved? Jews have no such fear. Are they saved? Buddhists? Etc. So I ask you. Is fear of hell the determining factor in knowing if one is saved?

Comment: @gideonmarx read his whole answer - you can't just take that part out of context

Comment: And do you see no contradiction between 'value God above all other things' and 'apart from the works of the law'? This implies a limit to the 'value' you place on God. His laws come second to faith. Is that God above all other things?

Comment: Even though I disagree with your premise, I don't disagree with your argument - there is so much truth here that I would give you +3 if I could - +2 for a great answer and +1 for the bruised reed reference.

Comment: @gideonmarx 'the works of the law' refers to your own attmepts at implementation of the law, not the law itself which is an expression of God's will and should be included therefore in valuing 'God above all other things.' But to proceed from there, how to rightly value the law, but not the works of the law is a complicated issue and the source of doctrinal division.

Comment: @bruisedreed - thanks for handling the rebuttals. cheers

Comment: @Mike it sounds like in your answer you're saying that only people who believe in Sola Fide get saved, is that right? And furthermore there seems to be a tautology: once saved always saved applies to those who persevere to the end. But then what is the point of once saved always saved? Is any human able to absolutely for sure 100% know that the Holy Spirit has regenerated them and they are saved? And what about the others who are not sure? You're saying if they're not saved cause they're not sure at times? What of those who are sure but wrong?

Comment: @GregoryMagarshak - (A1)Only to the degree that it is sola fide can it be genuine. If you said you believed in me but really meant you believed in something extra its just a play on words. (A2)The point of once saved always saved is because God's plans can't fail (election) and this to the encouragement of those who believe. (A3)Assurance is not always obtained by new believers right away. (A4) No. You do not have to be sure to be genuine. (A5) Those who deceive themselves will find they had no excuse at the judgment.) By the way for us who believe assurance/joy is fairly normal.